# Proper way to contain floating elements using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #container {
            border: 1px red solid;
        }
        .floaty {
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px green solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
    Text inside the container
    <div class='floaty'>
    Floaty block 1<br/>
    Floaty block 1<br/>
    Floaty block 1<br/>
    </div>
    <div class='floaty'>
    Floaty block 2<br/>
    Floaty block 2<br/>
    Floaty block 2<br/>
    </div>
    <div class='floaty'>
    Floaty block 3<br/>
    Floaty block 3<br/>
    Floaty block 3<br/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

This renders as: [image: floaty divs]

What's the proper CSS way to have the container (red-bordered box) completely surround the floaty green-bordered boxes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add an `overflow: auto` to the container, like this:

```
#container {
     border: 1px red solid;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

[You can test the effect here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/febyT/), and find [a very good description of how it works here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Comment: Will this work for all browsers? I don't have access to a Windows machine at the moment, so can't test IE.

Comment: @Roy - You may have to give the element a width in IE for it to behave correctly, just depends which versions you have to support.

Comment: It’s worth commenting your use of `overflow` to indicate that it’s intended to contain floats. Although this behaviour is correct as per the spec, it’s not the obvious result of applying `overflow`. I wish there was a `contain-floats: contain;` properly in CSS.

Comment: @Paul - I completely agree, and a decent replacement for `<center>` as well.  It seems completely ridiculous to me that this still isn't in CSS3. I'm well aware you can do it, but there's no simple replacement for *variable width* centering.

Comment: Did `<center>` ever do variable width centering? I guess it did with tables?

Answer (score 3):

add `overflow: auto` to the container or apply a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).

Answer (score 0):

[On modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/flow-root,css-containment), you can use `display: flow‑root;` or the `contain` property, which are the non‑hackish way to do this:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context